# Finding possible big theta for a given runtime function f(n)=O(n^2)+nlog(n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

> Suppose that f(*n*) = O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) + *n* log *n*. Which of the following are possible?
>
> 1. f(*n*) = Θ(log *n*)
> 2. f(*n*) = Θ(*n*)
> 3. f(*n*) = Θ(*n*<sup>2</sup>)
> 4. f(*n*) = Θ(*n*<sup>3</sup>)

I am a little confused about the runtime function, because of the included O(*n*<sup>2</sup>). I believe the answers are 2 and 3, because each of them can be multiplied by a number to reach the O(*n*<sup>2</sup>). Specifically, Θ(*n*<sup>2</sup>) can be multiplied by 1 to reach the upper bound O(*n*<sup>2</sup>), and Θ(*n*) can be multiplied by *n* to reach the upper bound O(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

Am I correct?

Comment: "Θ(n) can be multiplied by n to reach the upper bound O(n2)" - You can only multiply by constants.

Answer (score 5):

I guess the only correct answer is (3). `O(n^2)` is any function that grows as fast as `n^2` or slower. `n log n = O(n^2)`, so `O(n^2) + n log n` is any function that is asymptotically "between" `n log n` and `n^2`. Among all Thetas in your question only the third one fits into these bounds.

Answer (score 1):

f(n) = O(n^2) + nlogn means that there's a g(n) in O(n^2) such that f(n) = g(n) + nlogn.

g(n) in O(n^2) means that |g(n)| < cn^2 for some positive constant c, and all large enough n. The absolute value || bars in the definition allow for the possibility that g(n) is negative.

This means 1, 2, 3 can be the right answer. f(n) can't be negative because it describes a running time, but there's no reason why the O(n^2) term can't be negative.

1. g(n) = logn - nlogn is O(n^2), and g(n) + nlogn = logn.
2. g(n) = n - nlogn is O(n^2), and g(n) + nlogn = n
3. g(n) = n^2 - nlogn is O(n^2), and g(n) + nlogn = n^2
4. is not possible.

(Note the question is phrased in terms of big-theta, but it's possible for f(n) to match the bounds exactly in 1, 2, and 3).

3 is the only solution if you assume the O(n^2) term to be non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you go back to the definition of big theta when answering these types of questions. For a function `f` to be in `Θ(g(n))` of a function `g` a few things have to be true:

1. There exists a constant k<sub>1</sub> that is greater than 0
2. There exists a constant k<sub>2</sub> that is greater than 0
3. There exists some start value, n<sub>0</sub>
4. For all n > n<sub>0</sub>, k<sub>1</sub> * g(n) <= f(n) <= k<sub>2</sub> * g(n)

(4) basically means that as f(n) grows, k<sub>1</sub> * g(n) grows *slower* and k<sub>2</sub> * g(n) grows *faster* for the same n.

Luckily the relationship between these functions is really easy to see when they are plotted beside each other :)

Below we can see all the functions plotted alongside one another:

- blue is `f(n)`
- green is `log n`
- purple is `n`
- black is `n^2`
- red is `n^3`

[image: all functions plotted]

based on this plot, we can immediately discard `log n`, `n`, and `n^3` because there are no two *constants* we could bound these functions by that would grow in such a way that it bound `f(n)` as `n` grows.

`n^2` however looks promising. We just need to find two constants that allow `n^2` to bound the growth of `f(n)`.

Below we can see two such constants:

- blue is `f(n)`
- green is `1 * n^2`
- purple is `4 * n^2`

[image: 1*n^2 and 4*n^2 graphed alongside f(n)]

By finding these constants we can say definitively that `n^2 + n (log n)` is `Θ(n^2)`